# Scripts not working on StackOverflow site, but working on other StackExchange sites

Tags: firefox, javascript

Basically, JavaScript is not working only on the StackOverflow page and only for Firefox. It works on every other StackExchange site and every other non-StackExchange site I browse to, only StackOverflow is problematic. It is working fine in IE.

The only extension I have for Firefox is AdBlock+, but StackOverflow is whitelisted anyway. I've tried clearing the cache but no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: You might want to log this as a bug report at [MetaSO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: @DMA57361: I had thought about posting there but I figured it is more of a configuration problem on my end rather than a bug in StackExchange software, since it is working for IE but not Firefox.

Comment: Fair point. Have you tried any other browser for comparison (in case it's just IE working, rather than FF not working)? And have you tried with Firefox running in safe mode (to definitively rule out extensions as the cause).

Comment: Have you tried restarting Firefox.  I've seen this occasionally, but a restart always fixed it.

Comment: @KeithB: That was one of the first things I've tried (I admit I should have mentioned that), I even restarted my PC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was extreme, but after uninstalling Firefox and reinstalling it (losing all my preferences), scripts on StackOverflow are finally working again. I wish I didn't have to go that far but I suppose it's better than reformatting the hard disk.